# In java web aplication - Problem exporting Excel with Jxls

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jxls

i´m having trouble to export an excel file with the data of a query. I´m using java, spring, hibernate and Jxls. 
The idea is simple, use a button to export all the data in a table. When I click the button to generate the file this is the response that i´g getting:

**org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException**

My controller code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Controladores;

import Modelos.HibernateUtil;
import Modelos.Venta;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.jxls.template.SimpleExporter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reporte.htm")
public class CReporte {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String metodoGet(HttpServletResponse response) {
        return "vReporte";
    }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String exportar(HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("entro en funcion");
        List<Venta> venta = obtenerVentas();
        System.out.println("obtener ventas: "+ venta);
        List<String> headers = Arrays.asList("PRODUCTO Nro", "ID DE TRANSACCION", "MONTO", "FECHA DE VENTA");
        System.out.println("headers: "+ headers);
        try {
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Ventas.xlsx");
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            new SimpleExporter().gridExport(headers, venta, "idProducto, idVenta,mont,fechaVenta ", response.getOutputStream());
            response.flushBuffer();
            return "inicio";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "error";
        }

    }


    private List obtenerVentas() {

        try {

            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            List result = session.createQuery("from Venta").list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
            return result;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("aca en exception?");
            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

My view code:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : vReporte
    Created on : 23/02/2020, 13:00:11
    Author     : jsabate
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Reporte</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <br></br>
        <form action="reporte.htm" method="POST">
            <br></br>
            <br>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="generate" value="Generar">
                        <input type="button" name="back" value="Inicio"onclick="window.location.href='inicio.htm'" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my glassfish log:

```
Información:   HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
WARN:   HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Información:   HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto_bd]
Información:   HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root}
Información:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Información:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Información:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Información:   HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Información:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Información:   obtener ventas: [Modelos.Venta@8f2c0c, Modelos.Venta@2d497dc0, Modelos.Venta@4db620b7, Modelos.Venta@28b400f6]
Información:   headers: [PRODUCTO Nro, ID DE TRANSACCION, MONTO, FECHA DE VENTA]
Grave:   6 [http-listener-1(5)] INFO org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Loading transformer by class org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer
Grave:   113 [http-listener-1(5)] ERROR org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory - Method createTransformer of org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer class thrown an Exception
Grave:   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jxls.util.TransformerFactory.createTransformer(TransformerFactory.java:43)
    at org.jxls.template.SimpleExporter.gridExport(SimpleExporter.java:56)
    at Controladores.CReporte.exportar(CReporte.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/util/ArithmeticUtils
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.RootProperty.setSize(RootProperty.java:59)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.DirectoryProperty.<init>(DirectoryProperty.java:52)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.RootProperty.<init>(RootProperty.java:31)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.property.PropertyTable.<init>(PropertyTable.java:58)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:102)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:274)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:252)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:221)
    at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:134)
    at org.jxls.transform.poi.PoiTransformer.createTransformer(PoiTransformer.java:120)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.util.ArithmeticUtils
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    ... 64 more
Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jxls.builder.xls.XlsCommentAreaBuilder.build(XlsCommentAreaBuilder.java:167)
    at org.jxls.template.SimpleExporter.gridExport(SimpleExporter.java:58)
    at Controladores.CReporte.exportar(CReporte.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What line is triggering this error?

Comment: please post the complete stack trace..

Comment: Hello @EricLang Im not sure what is triggering the error, it happens after the sumbit button somewhere on my export method ***exportar*** i get that error, i know in the headers list its ok (for the logs).

Comment: @SantosshKumhar i edit the post an add the glassfish log